# Draw Letters In Turtle

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I just started learning turtle in python.
I am tried to write my name "Idan" (capital letters), but I am stuck on "D".

This is my code so far:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

t.up()
t.backward(400)
t.left(90)
t.down()
t.forward(250)
t.right(90)
t.forward(62.5)
t.backward(62.5 * 2)
t.forward(62.5)
t.right(90)
t.forward(250)
t.right(90)
t.forward(62.5)
t.backward(62.5 * 2)
t.up()
t.backward(100)
t.right(90)
t.down()
t.forward(250)
for x in range(180):
    t.forward(1)
    t.right(1)
```

But when I run it it gives me a small half circle.

Is there a way to make it do a half circle that will create a "D"

Comment: You can use [`turtle.circle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle) to draw semicircles (i.e. arcs).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you have is that your half-circle starts when the turtle is facing up, rather than to the right. Add a `t.right(90)` call just before the `for` loop and you'll be closer to what you want (you'll get something like a `P`).

After that, you'll need to adjust the `forward` calls inside the loop to make the circle the size you want (or as [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) suggested in a comment, use `t.circle` instead of your own loop). You might need to do some calculations to figure out the right distances (e.g. multiply your desired diameter by `math.pi` to get a circumference, then divide by the number of segments you're using to construct it).

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, made by try and error, but it writes the name:

```
import turtle
turtle.setup(900,400)
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Turtle writing my name: IDAN")
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
turtle.width(30)
# turtle.pensize(30)

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.up()
t.backward(360)
t.left(90)
t.backward(80)
t.down()
t.forward(250)
t.right(90)
t.forward(62.5)
t.backward(62.5 * 2)
t.forward(62.5)
t.right(90)
t.forward(250)
t.right(90)
t.forward(62.5)
t.backward(62.5 * 2)
t.up()
t.backward(100)
t.right(90)
t.down()
t.forward(250)
t.right(90)
for x in range(180):
```

> `. t.forward(2.2) # adjust HERE to get different size of circle`

```
    t.right(1)
t.up()
t.right(90)
t.forward(230)
t.right(90)
t.forward(4*62.5)
t.right(65)
t.down()
t.forward(250)
t.right(180)
t.forward(275)
t.left(135)
t.forward(250)
t.right(180)
t.forward(120)
t.right(70)
t.forward(110)
t.right(90)
t.up()
t.forward(115)
t.left(90)
t.forward(1.5*62.5)
t.left(90)
t.down()
t.forward(250)
t.right(145)
t.forward(320)
t.left(145)
t.forward(250)

wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following in solving a problem like this:

- Plan out your block font carefully ahead, on paper if needed.  The
  simpler your design, the easier it will be to code.
- Separate your letters logically in your code -- if not into functions
  at this point, at least into separate commented blocks.
- Have each letter start with the turtle pointing the same direction
  and adjust as necessary, don't count on the resulting state of the previous
  letter.
- Use a virtual coordinate system to simplify your drawing logic and
  allow the letters to appear in different size windows.  If not with a
  function like `setworldcoordinates()` then simply via multipliers for
  the height and width.
- Assume in your design that you'll want to add more letters later.
- Consider what would happen if you wanted to spell "DIAN" instead --
  how much code would you have to change and how can you keep this to a
  minimum.

My example below uses features you've probably not learned yet and is not meant as a solution for you to use -- it's meant to illustrate the above ideas.  I.e. try changing the window size, the border size, the width and height, rearrange the leters, etc. and see how the results change but still work:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

NAME = "IDAN"

BORDER = 1
BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT = 6, 10  # letter bounding box
WIDTH, HEIGHT = BOX_WIDTH - BORDER * 2, BOX_HEIGHT - BORDER * 2  # letter size

def letter_A(turtle):
    turtle.forward(HEIGHT / 2)
    for _ in range(3):
        turtle.forward(HEIGHT / 2)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(WIDTH)
        turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(HEIGHT)

def letter_D(turtle):
    turtle.forward(HEIGHT)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.circle(-HEIGHT / 2, 180, 30)

def letter_I(turtle):
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(WIDTH)
    turtle.backward(WIDTH / 2)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(HEIGHT)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.backward(WIDTH / 2)
    turtle.forward(WIDTH)

def letter_N(turtle):
    turtle.forward(HEIGHT)
    turtle.goto(turtle.xcor() + WIDTH, BORDER)
    turtle.forward(HEIGHT)

LETTERS = {'A': letter_A, 'D': letter_D, 'I': letter_I, 'N': letter_N}

wn = Screen()
wn.setup(800, 400)  # arbitrary
wn.title("Turtle writing my name: {}".format(NAME))
wn.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, BOX_WIDTH * len(NAME), BOX_HEIGHT)

marker = Turtle()

for counter, letter in enumerate(NAME):
    marker.penup()
    marker.goto(counter * BOX_WIDTH + BORDER, BORDER)
    marker.setheading(90)

    if letter in LETTERS:
        marker.pendown()
        LETTERS[letter](marker)

marker.hideturtle()

wn.mainloop()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code instead:

```
import turtle
turtle = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.write("IDAN", font=("Arial", 32, "normal"))
```

Comment: can you please explain how this write command is going to draw semi-circle.

Comment: this code will write a the text "IDAN". However, you can not use this code to make a semi-circle alone. You can also replace "IDAN" with whatever word or sentence you want to write out but it can only write the letters, numbers or symbols on your keyboard

Answer (score 0):

This might work:
It works for me

```
import turtle as t    

def letterD():
    t.pendown()
    t.setheading(90)
    t.forward(108)
    t.setheading(0)
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(20)
        t.right(30)
    t.setheading(-90)
    t.forward(13)
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(20)
        t.right(30)
    t.setheading(0)
    t.penup()
    t.forward(65)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Pen()
t.circle(50, 180)

# this draws a 180 degree, 50 radius circle
```

Answer (score 0):

**I Use Google Colab So This is the Code for that Program**

```
!pip3 install ColabTurtle

import ColabTurtle.Turtle as l    
l.initializeTurtle()    
l.width(6)    
l.penup()    
l.right(270)    
l.forward(300)    
l.right(180)    
l.forward(100)    
l.left(180)    
l.pendown()    
l.forward(100)    
l.right(90)    
l.forward(150)    
l.penup()    
l.right(90)    
l.forward(130)    
l.pendown()    
l.right(90)    
l.forward(150)    
l.left(90)    
l.forward(100)    
l.left(90)    
l.forward(150)    
l.penup()    
l.right(90)    
l.forward(30)    
l.right(45)    
l.pendown()    
l.forward(200)   
l.penup()    
l.left(45)    
l.left(90)    
l.forward(150)    
l.left(90)    
l.left(45)    
l.pendown()    
l.forward(200)    
l.penup()    
l.left(45)    
l.left(90)    
l.forward(200)    
l.left(90)
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]